# I may have given ID card and personal details to scammers

Tags: scams

I had an interview for a virtual assistant position at a working site. The  interview took place on this page until they said they want a long term agreement that must be made off  site.

In short,  we're connecting on the email and they informed me that based on the interview I've been chosen for the job. They then asked me to fill the form, which I did. After sending this, they asked for my ID which I provided. After that, they said that  I had to  send them my passport and business license. I sensed that this is wrong because in my previous positions,  after sending in my ID and picture, they always sent me an agreement to review. I tried  to determine  if this is a scam but I could not. This is what makes me think it was scam:

1. They said that they work for Union Beverage Factory LLC (Dubai).  I searched on Linkedin but none of them have an account or work there.
2. I'm in contact with three people: Akeem from HR, Abdulaziz from finance and Dennis from sales.  All of them using Gmail and hang out to communicate.
3. HR asked me to confirm their partner but they send MW back with some information like salary details, etc. This doesn't  make sense and now I am worried  about my ID and personal details that I've sent them. What's the  worst that  can happen?

Comment: To confirm: did you **refrain** from sending a copy of your passport?

Comment: Fortunately no, i'm just sending all details in form and a copy of my id.

Comment: Well, you normally show your ID to strangers, so while "the worst that can happen" is really bad, they didn't get what they really want.  You did good here, I think.

Comment: I hope there's nothing bad happened. when they ask more document including my passport fortunately my brain still thinking twice before send them. Thank you RonJohn.

Comment: I would suggest, just to be safe, you immediately change your mother's maiden name, the street you grew up on, and where you went on your honeymoon.

Comment: Hi David, is it any connection with the information I sent them?